# Use of Promise returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have written this service

```
var app = angular.module('Todo', []);

app.service('$SharePointJSOMService', function ($q, $http) {
    this.getListItems = function ($scope, listTitle) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //First we must call the EnsureSetup method
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);
        var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=Title&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: restQueryUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log('call was a success');
                console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('call failed');
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    };
});
```

I call this service in my controller

```
app.controller('TodoController', function ($scope, $SharePointJSOMService) {
    $scope.todos = [];
    var promise = $SharePointJSOMService.getListItems($scope, 'TodoList');
    promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log("came inside the promise success method");
        $scope.todos = [];        
        angular.forEach(data.data.d.results, function (todo) {
            console.log(todo);
            $scope.todo.push({
                text: todo.Title
            });
        });
    }, function (data) {
        console.log("Error " + data);
    });
}); // controller
```

In the log I can see

```
call was a success App.js:17
Object {d: Object} App.js:18
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://app-6c6f508a56f90c.abhiapps.com/HelloWorld/Scripts/App.js:83:13)
    at invoke (http://app-6c6f508a56f90c.abhiapps.com/HelloWorld/Scripts/angular.js:3966:17)
```

So in the service method the call is a success and I can see that it prints the right results. But when I call "promise.then" method in controller I get undefined for promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to return the promise, not just the 'deferred'.

```
return deferred.promise;
```